Receiving a char array to a void pointer shows different behavior
I am attempting to develop a method to customize strcpy. I considered two approaches for this implementation. One method involves using memcpy, while the other involves incrementing the pointer and assigning the value.
Implementation using memcpy worked as expected. Code snippet is pasted below.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void mystrcpy(void *dest, void *src, size_t size)
{

    memcpy((char*)dest,(char*)src,size);
    printf("Final - %s\n",(char*)dest);
}



int main()
{
    char *src = "ABC";
    char dest[20];
    printf("%p %p\n",src,dest);
    mystrcpy(dest,src,4);

    return 0;
}

Output is below:
000000000040400C 000000000061FE00
Final - ABC

Hence, I had gone for the second implementation and it is not fully completed.  Since I'm just getting started, I saw some behavior that wasn't what I had anticipated. I am not sure about this. May be I am lagging some very important concepts here.
Here, I consider taking two void* parameters for source and destination. Something similar to below.
void mystrcpy(void *dest, void *src)

Pasting my code below,
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void mystrcpy(void *dest, void *src)
{

    char *_dest = (char*)dest;
    char *_src = (char*)src;

    *_dest = *_src;
    printf("%c %c\n",*_src,*_dest);
    printf("%p %p\n",_src,_dest);
    _src++ ; _dest++;


    *_dest = *_src;
    printf("%c %c\n",*_src,*_dest);
    printf("%p %p\n",_src,_dest);
    _src++ ; _dest++;


    *_dest = *_src;
    printf("%c %c\n",*_src,*_dest);
    printf("%p %p\n",_src,_dest);
    _src++ ; _dest++;

    *_dest = '\0';

    printf("Final - %d %d %d  %p %p %p\n",_dest[0],_dest[1],_dest[2],&_dest[0],&_dest[1],&_dest[2]);
}



int main()
{
    char *src = "ABC";
    char dest[20];
    printf("%p %p\n",src,dest);
    mystrcpy(dest,src);

    return 0;
}

And the output shows

0000000000404034 000000000061FE00


A A


0000000000404034 000000000061FE00


B B


0000000000404035 000000000061FE01


C C


0000000000404036 000000000061FE02


Final - 0 0 0  000000000061FE03 000000000061FE04 000000000061FE05

It was copying the value as expected. I am just confused on the last print,
how it went to xxx03  xxx04 xxx05 instead of xxx00 xxx01 xxx03 !!. And this is the reason why I got garbage value when I printed the _dest.
Please share your thoughts on this.
Thanks in advance.

The "issue" you're encountering in the unexpected value being printed has nothing to do with the void pointers, but rather in the fact that you're incrementing _dest, which ends up pointer to the character after C. I'm not sure why you're using void * for strings, you just end up converting back and forth. Also, the printf "%p" format specifier expects a void *, not a char *. While this is unlikely to cause issues on typical platforms, you should cast to void * there.

sizeof(src) is the size of a pointer, not the string length.

In mystrcpy() you're incrementing _dest as you go, so e.g. _dest[0] in the printf probably means something other than what you thought when you wrote that statement.

If you have e.g. int i = 5; and then do i++ would you still expect i to be equal to 5? Because that is basically what your function expects, that once you have modified _dest it will still be the same as the original value passed to the function.

@ThomasJager: The C standard specifies that void * and char * have the same size and representation, and it notes the intent is they be interchangeable as arguments to functions. Using one for the other this way will not cause a problem in a conforming C implementation.

@Someprogrammerdude But, as you can see, I am just checking the initial value of _dest. How the value assigned to those get unreflected. I hope, I am not incrementing the content, instead the pointer. Please help.

@EricPostpischil Ah my bad, that part of my original comment should be ignored.

_dest++ is the same as _dest = _dest + 1. You understand that? It means the value of _dest that was passed to your function is lost. So after the tree modifications to _dest, _dest[0] will actually be equal to original_dest[3].

@Someprogrammerdude Isn't a pointer ? Pointer arithmetic says that incrementing the address by +1 for char*. ?

Yes, but you change where _dest is pointing. I'll write an answer with some drawing to help you understand (I hope).

@Someprogrammerdude Why same thing was not applicable for _src++. It incremented as expected. It would be really realy great if you can explain that

@Someprogrammerdude Also, please help me on how to resolve this issue. How to modify the code so that I will get the expected output. I am not sure with the current implementation is possible or not. I am just trying to understand that.

No the same thing happens for _src and its increments. The difference is that once you have changed it, you don't use it any more.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

It's just a silly typo on the last line of the function, should be dest not _dest in the printf.

Lets make a much simpler function:
void test(char *dest)
{
    char *original_dest = dest;  // Now both variables points to the same location

    dest++;  // Now dest points somewhere else
}

After the initialization of original_dest, the memory looks something like this:

+------+
| dest | -----------\
+------+             \     +---+---+---+----
                      >--> | 0 | 1 | 2 | ...
+---------------+    /     +---+---+---+----
| original_dest | --/
+---------------+

Both pointers are pointing to the same location.
But after dest++ it will look like this:

+------+
| dest | ------------------\
+------+                    |
                            v
+---------------+     +---+---+---+----
| original_dest | --> | 0 | 1 | 2 | ...
+---------------+     +---+---+---+----

So original_dest still points to the same original element it did before, but dest now points to a different element.

It's really equivalent to something like this:
void func(int a)
{
    int b = a;  // Copy the value to a new variable

    a++;  // Change the value of a

    // Here the variable b will have have one value,
    // and a will have a different value
    // You can no longer use the variable a to get back the original
    // value that was passed to the function
}


To hep understand pointers, I always recommend using pencil and paper to draw everything, to better visualize pointers and how they work.
Use labeled boxes for the variables and arrays, and arrows for the pointers. When you modify a pointer variable (like for example _dest++) you erase and redraw the arrow from it.

Ok . Understood. Thank you.

Thank you and Upvoted for the explanation


how it went to xxx03 xxx04 xxx05 instead of xxx00 xxx01 xxx03

The code does:
void mystrcpy(void *dest, void *src) {
    char *_dest = (char*)dest;
    _dest++;
    _dest++;
    _dest++;
    printf("Final - %d %d %d  %p %p %p\n",_dest[0],_dest[1],_dest[2],&_dest[0],&_dest[1],&_dest[2]);
}

So _dest is incremented 3 times - xxx00 -> xxx01 -> xxx02 -> xxx03. So after 3 increments _dest is at xxx03.
Most probably, you meant to:
printf("Final - %d %d %d  %p %p %p\n", dest[0], dest[1], dest[2],  &dest[0],  &dest[1], &dest[2]);

which is not possible because dest is a void *. So cast it:
printf("Final - %d %d %d  %p %p %p\n", ((char*)dest)[0], ((char*)dest)[1], ((char*)dest)[2],  &((char*)dest)[0],  &((char*)dest)[1], &((char*)dest)[2]);

or with a temporary variable, as you did:
char *p = dest;
printf("Final - %d %d %d  %p %p %p\n", p[0], p[1], p[2], &p[0],  &p[1], &p[2]);


Thank you so much for taking some time for this.   Regarding the answer you posted --> No. As you can see in the code, I am doing *_dest = *_src;, Here I meant to copy the content of *_src to *_dest at the initial location. So that I can print the new _dest and not the old dest

Thank you and Upvoted for the explanation

dest[0] - I cannot do that because it will throw an error  for dereferencing a void pointer

hi @VishnuCS  So that I can print the new _dest and not the old dest I have no idea what you mean. Coping the pointed to value does not affect the pointer value. The code increments _dest, so _dest values changes so it can't be used, or it can be decremented _dest -= 3 back.  I think there might be misunderstanding what are "pointers" by themselves, and I think it will be really hard to explain or learn it using stackoverflow. Consider researching what are pointers and multiple introductions to them online. I cannot do that you are right, edited.

Hi @KamilCuk - Understood your point. Please see my below answer. This is what I expected.

As @Someprogrammerdude and @KamilCuk suggestions, I understood that my _dest memory address moved ahead by +3 (since I performed three times _dest++). So, I modified my printf function to print the data we stored inside _dest by moving behind (_dest[-1],_dest[-2],_dest[-3]) the array index.
printf("Final - %c %c %c  %p %p %p\n",_dest[-1],_dest[-2],_dest[-3],&_dest[-1],&_dest[-2],&_dest[-3]);

And it printed
Final - C B A  000000000061FE02 000000000061FE01 000000000061FE00

or another easy way to print out the content is as below,
printf("%s\n",(char*)dest);

Output would be as below
ABC

I am just posting the answer because this may be helpful to some others.
Thank you all for giving such welcoming suggestions and clarities. :)

void mystrcpy(void *dest, void *src, size_t size)
{

    memcpy((char*)dest,(char*)src,size);
    printf("Final - %s\n",(char*)dest);
}

dest pointer is passed by value to memcpy() so it is never expected to change.  You will get the same value as you received it from main()
